# R / RMariaDB: How to avoid "Lost connection to server during query" in a loop

Tags: r, rmariadb

I use `RMariaDB::dbConnect()` to establish a connection to my MySQL database in R.

It works well, but during a long `for`-loop where I insert values into the database with each iteration (using `dbSendStatement()`), it happens every so often that I get the error:

**Error: Lost connection to server during query [2013]**

Is there any way to avoid it?

Are there any (dis-)advantages when I simply include a `RMariaDB::dbConnect()` in the beginning of *every single iteration*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer based on the `%%`-operator.

I basically disconnect and reconnect every nth (here: 15th) iteration:

```
for(i in 1:5000) {

   if (i %% 15 == 0) {
    
       print("Reconnecting to MySQL...")
    
       dbDisconnect(stuffDB)
    
       stuffDB <- dbConnect(MariaDB(), user = "x", password = "x", dbname = "x", host = "x")
    
     }

}
```